# Is it possible to change the direction of shadows when using an HDRI for lighting without affecting the color?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, hdri

I want to create 2 images with mirrored lighting. The direction of the shadows is not particularly important. It is only important that the second image casts a shadow that goes exactly into the opposite direction. I use an HDRI without additional light sources for the lighting. The light source appears to be in the upper right corner as the shadow points to the lower left.

[image: HDRI lighting from top right]

Whatever I try to change the direction of the shadows changes the color significantly. Is it possible to mirror the HDRI horizontally without affecting the color?

The example file can be downloaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/t/YtmJLA9vNr0zcF5Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this video that might help:
https://www.blendernation.com/2017/08/30/control-hdr-shadows-blender/

Answer (score 0):

HDRI coordinates can be adjusted using the *Mapping* node. First, it is recommended to enable the *Node Wrangler* addon. While the HDRI node is selected, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to add *Texture Coordinate* and *Mapping* node. In *Mapping* try scaling by $-1$ in X or Y for a mirror effect.